# Programmatically switching between Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to switch between 2 Fragments located in 1 activity, so the other fragment should always replace the current one. I can´t find my error though :(

My main activity:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

    Fragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.container, fragment, "first");
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

My activity_layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Now, at some point within the logic of the FirstFragment (which works fine), the following method is being called

```
    private void startSecondFragment(){

    Fragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.container, fragment, "second");
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

This function does finish without an error, however right afterwards the following exception is getting thrown:

```
02-11 13:40:30.533: E/AndroidRuntime(907): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f070000 (com.myexample.app:id/container) for fragment SecondFragment{412c9388 #0 id=0x7f070000 second}
```

Now, it seems like its not able to find the id "container" at this point (the first Fragment has replaced this container). How can I really *replace* the first fragment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
private void startSecondFragment(){

    Fragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.container, fragment, "second");
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

You don't want to get child's FragmentManager, because your fragments are in your Activity, so you need the same fragmentManager.