# Fragment is not fully covering parent activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

There is `Button` in `Activity` when we click on `Button` fragment's view overlaps `Activity's` view .

When `Button` is clicked it is forwarded to `Fragment`. Problem is it overlaps with `Button`.

In `MainActivity` i have created `Button` and set listener on that when user click on `Button` it is forwarded to fragment file which contain only textview.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {        
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {                 
                       fragment fr = new fragment();                                                   
                      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.parent_frame, fr).commit();            
                }                   
           });          
         }      
}
```

**fragment.java**

```
 public class fragment extends Fragment {

      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment,  container, false);
        return view;
      }

    }
```

**fragment.xml :**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">       

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detailsText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Default Text ggggggg"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="30dip" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press to update"
         />

    <fragment
        class="com.example.demo3.fragment"
      android:id="@+id/parent_frame"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: We can't do anything without any layout xml.

Comment: jay's solution will work here as there is only one button. What if one have quite complex layout ? why this strange behavior is seen here ?

Comment: which complex layout?

Comment: @Jay: In stead of single button there could be bunch of view elements listview, spinners,edittext etc..

Comment: in that case take one parent Relative layout and create two child layout with match parent property 1 is frame layout 2 is your own layout then initially framelayout gone and your second layout work in mainActivity class when you want to display fragment just visible to your framlayout in xml and gone your second layout...thats it...understend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why aren't you using the Activity merely as a container, and use Fragments for ALL ui elements, including the button you are clicking to change between them?

Something like this: [Programatically switching between Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812554/programatically-switching-between-fragments)

Comment: (Or consider a custom view-group approach.)

Answer (score 1):

this is unique thought and i appreciate it.if you want to do this just follow below steps:

1) in your activity main take framelayout with height width system fit(matchparent) and id is parent_frame

2) take button inside it and when you click on it set button visible to gone

3) then you can add fragment to this framlayout

Make sure in your activity_main must contain framlayout with matchparent